# Force 2 copies of the same file to be stored on 2 different sectors of hard disk

Tags: hard-drive, file-management

I am concerned about hard disk sector failures. I have a small file that I want to protect. If the sector that the file is stored on fails, then the file is lost, right? So I want to save two copies of the file, each copy should reside on a different sector. How do I ensure that the two files are stored on different sectors?

If it is possible to defend against other hard disk failures, such as bad blocks instead of bad sectors, then I would like to know how to defend against those as well.

I am following the "multiple copies on multiple hard drives" backup strategy. I am using this strategy in addition to, rather than instead of, storing the file on multiple hard drives.

Comment: Its better to store it on another drive or storage medium. Your making it too complicated to back up files.

Comment: @Moab: Agreed. I don't know how important this single file is to the OP (must be), but this is turning into some theoretical experiment, instead of a pratical question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They always will be.
By definition.
Two files cannot occupy the same space.

*After your edit -* For these purposes 'block' & 'sector' are the same thing.
If your concern is really at the sector level, you are worrying about the wrong thing. An old spinning rust HD *may* fail slowly, in a genteel manner, giving you weeks of preparation to move your data safely to another drive… or it may just catastrophically fail completely & utterly with no prior warning at all.
…or the house may burn down.

If you really need data security, then two copies on one disk is *nowhere near* sufficient.

There's an adage…
"Any data not stored in at least three distinct locations should be considered temporary."

You "defend" against sector failure by never entrusting your data to one location. You cannot dictate precisely where data on a drive is stored, nor would making sure another copy was on a different platter make it any more secure. You cannot 'do maintenance' on a drive in any meaningful way as regards the longevity of any given sector.

Your two copies still only qualify as one location.
You need a proper backup solution, one in-house [on at least a different drive, though preferably a different computer] & a second off-site, to even reach the bare minimum safety-level for your data.

Comment: [...Two files cannot occupy the same space...]
That is wrong. They can very well occupy the same space but this possibility depends on the file system used. Think about UNIX type file systems. FAT32 cannot achieve that. NTFS can do it (hard links).

Comment: You mean 2 files cannot occupy the same sector? But they can still occupy the same block, right?

Comment: Most files systems manage storage in blocks, also called cluster. A rare exceptions is ReiserFS as far as I remember. The "block" level is a level above sector level. For the guy asking the question you can use the terms sector, block and cluster interchangeably.

Comment: The same as anything physical - two spoons in a drawer cannot occupy the same space, no matter how you stack them. [Note to anyone more au fait with this, I'm ignoring any type of hard-link structure for this explanation]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many partitions you have on your hard drive (I presume it's not an SSD?), you have several possibilities:

1) Intall a cloud app like Dropbox ou pCloud and save the file there

2) Create a new partition separated from your system/storage one by free space, format it (NTFS is preferable), and store your file there. It'll be as physically separated from the other copy as is possible (EDIT) *while staying on the same drive*.

Comment: 2 is not good enough.

Comment: Presumably, the OP is worried about disk *sector* failure, not a complete disk failure, so it *could* be deemed good enough by the OP, unless he/she is ready to shell out the money to buy a separate drive or computer just for one file...

Comment: tbh, it's the wrong thing to worry about.

Comment: @Tetsujin: Agreed, again. I understand how paranoid one can be about protecting important data, and I'm sure this file really is important to the OP, but still, worrying about ONE bad sector on a whole drive... Plus, we don't know the size of the file. For all we know, it could be several MB or GB in size, and be distributed on several sectors of the drive, adjacent or not, depending on write speed and available space when the file was created...

Comment: Why separated by free space? Why would NFTS be preferable? (i.e: [vs another system that ensures file integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#File_capabilities) for example) Who said Windows?

Comment: You're right, too many unknowns, I give up, but to answer your questions, *supposing* the OS *is* Windows, then NTFS is the go-to file system because it's natively supported by Windows, readable-writable by most OSes, has a very high size limit for single files, and the empty space (preferably several GB) would guarantee (sort of) that the copy of this mysterious file would *probably* be located on a different sector of the drive. The more to the right in Disk Manager, the farther from the disk periphery. *If* we're talking about a regular HDD and not an SSD. As I said, too many unknowns...

Answer (score 0):

[...How do I ensure that the two files are stored on different sectors?...]

As there might be situation where you cannot determine the file systems or its setting, just put your file into an archive like 7z, rar or zip enforcing compression even when the compression ratio is bad (jpeg p.e.). That will change your file sufficiently to avoid storing on a unique location when storing the backup on the same drive. Unfortunately this is not a backup solution. There are many failures types that will affect both files.

The best would be to store a physical copy with your relatives at some remote location.